# Merging two functions together

Tags: jquery, function, merge

I have two functions:

1) The box is hidden on pageload. When the user scrolls down the page so much, a box should slide in. When they choose the close the box, the box hides.

2)When they close the box, this box should stay closed when the navigate to other pages (im using cookies to do this),

Trying to implement the two functions together seems to be the issue and conflicts with each other. Can someone give me some guidance as when putting the scroll function within the cookie it hides the box completely.

Here is the code (all code works separately):

**Scrolling Code:**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            jQuery('#test').stop().animate({ left: '0' });
        } else {
            jQuery('#test').stop().animate({ left: '-25%' });
        }
    });
```

**Cookie code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#test').show();
  }
  // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
  // not show it again until one day has passed.
  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#test').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
});
```

**html dummy text**

```
<div id="test">poup with stuff in it
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="close">close</a>
</div>
```

Im a novice user to this so i know i have working code it's just putting the 2 together, any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hiding the div upon initial display using the CSS `display: none;` property? I can get your code to work as seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t35cq/1/.

CSS:

```
.main {
    height: 1000px;
}
.test {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='main'>
    <div id="test" class='test'>poup with stuff in it <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="close">close</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        jQuery('#test').stop().animate({
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('#test').stop().animate({
            left: '-100%'
        });
    }
});

// Manually display or hide using code.
//createCookie('hide', true, 1);
eraseCookie('hide');

$(document).ready(function () {
    // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
    if (!readCookie('hide')) {
        console.log('x');
        $('#test').show();
    }
    // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
    // not show it again until one day has passed.
    $('#close').click(function () {
        $('#test').hide();
        createCookie('hide', true, 1)
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Your code nearly works! as it does not show again if you scroll up and back down again on the same page but when you go onto another page it slides in, ignoring the cookie function :( Tried this by refreshing the fiddle and comes back when it should'nt (if this makes sense) thanks for the advice.

Comment: I was manually erasing the cookie in the middle of the code, and accidentally forgot to take out the `eraseCookie('hide');` call. When you take that out, it works as intended. (PS: Don't forget to vote for the correct answer).

Comment: Well thank you so much! For some reason it wouldn't let me up vote or mark your answer as correct then realised of course clearing my cache and cookie settings logged me out! haha. Thank you.

Comment: Can i ask- how to do this if it was a fadeIn/Out instead of slide? Altering the JS makes the slider shown and the css conflicts- sorry for another question.

Comment: The simplest way I can see is to add opacity to the animation (See: http://jsfiddle.net/t35cq/5/). I'm not sure how cross-browser this approach is, though. http://caniuse.com/css-opacity tells me that IE8 does not support this.